# How to make scope variable usable in the rest of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

To build some conditional fields on values chosen in parent fields, I have the following html code:

```
<select id="fad_typedebien" name="goodtype" required="" class="field_required form-control">
  <option value="">Type de bien</option>
  <option value="Appartements">Appartements</option>
  <option value="Bureaux">Bureaux</option>
  <option value="Espaces commerciaux">Espaces commerciaux</option>
  <option value="Immeubles">Immeubles</option>
  <option value="Maisons">Maisons</option>
  <option value="Terrains">Terrains</option>
</select>
```

Now I have a part of Jquery code which is :

```
var selectedValue;
    jQ('#adminForm #fad_typedebien).change(function() {
        selectedValue = jQ(this).val(); 
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < parentvalues.length; i++) {
        if (selectedValue == parentvalues[i] && find == false) {
            jQ('#adminForm #f'+child).show();
            jQ('#adminForm #row_'+child).show();
            find = true;
        }
    }
```

I can not see any value on alert of selectedValue variable. I am trying to make a child field appears when select some selected choces in the list. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing ending  `'` here:- `jQ('#adminForm #fad_typedebien)`. Correct it and check

Comment: You have to wait for the event to occur

Comment: the `for` loop should be inside the `change` function for it to occur each time an element is selected. You also should correct your `'` syntax as stated in first comment, and should also declare the `find` var inside this function (not vital, but it won't end up being global)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```js
var myArray = ['Appartements'];
var selectedValue = $('#fad_typedebien').value;

function myFunction (e) {
    selectedValue = e.value;
    alert(selectedValue);
    if(myArray.indexOf(e.value) > -1) {
        console.log('found');
        $('#childField').css('display', 'inline-block');
    } else {
        console.log('not found');
        $('#childField').css('display', 'none');
    }
}
```

```css
#childField {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="myFunction(this)" id="fad_typedebien" name="goodtype" required="" class="field_required form-control">
  <option value="">Type de bien</option>
  <option value="Appartements">Appartements</option>
  <option value="Bureaux">Bureaux</option>
  <option value="Espaces commerciaux">Espaces commerciaux</option>
  <option value="Immeubles">Immeubles</option>
  <option value="Maisons">Maisons</option>
  <option value="Terrains">Terrains</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="childField">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you suggest. Actually, I want to make child field appears only for some values in parent list.

Comment: Yes this is what I need to have. But, the real problem is on the scope of value.. when I do an alert on selectedValue, I have an empty result. I do not know why the variable does not get option values.

Comment: Works fine for me. You mean that 'selectedValue' is undefined when alerting? Maybe you've tried to alert the variable before the dom was rendered. Could you add some explanation or a fiddle?

Comment: Okay Wouter.. can I send you my file and link in private ?

Comment: I suggest you try to create a fiddle where you can showcase your problem without any code that is not related.